# Drupal 6 Linking anonymous user and content created by him

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am newbie to Drupal 6.

My requirement is that any anonymous user can come and create content of particular content type. Before saving content to the database,I need to capture his email address so that I can send him a link to view,edit and delete for the content created.

Here I thought that before sending mail, I'll make an entry in the user's table with email address registered. So that I can make a relationship between content he has created.

But problem may be if such user wants to register with site, then Druapl's registration process'll stop him to register as email address already exist in database.

Is it possible something like; assign unregistered role for such users and on registration page check for email address and unregistered role in combination.

Or something better idea?

Could you please guide me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one idea :P

1 -> Register user on database 
       a) generate random password
       b) create module that override login process (add a Status:
Blocked
Active
***(Pre-Active)**

2 -> Inside that mail you send him:

Hi ....,

You have new module ....

your credentials are:

Login: xxx@xxx.com
Pwd: xxxxxx

3 -> when he returns your site and make login, you change status and send him for his user information....

Hope it helps

- User has to be registered because otherwise you can't control permissions on that content type (edit, delete)
- If you put him as active, you can have a lot of users active but just have been there once!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve your problem with http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan

This will allow you to create a "preregistered" user role and register users using that role when they  first create content. There are a number of options from there as to how you can handle how users that later sign up, and what they can do with their own content.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do this? Allowing anonymous users to post content to your site is going to lead to massive abuses. Prepare for the entire site to be filled with spam and Google-gaming links to porn/viagra/etc.

Comment: Posted contents are not going to be published unless you receive mail asking you to confirm message. Once confirmed then only your message gets visible on portal. Clients requirement...!

Comment: You will still get a lot of auto-spam. I did on my personal Drupal site until I added a Captcha. The spam-bots don't care if it will be visible or not; they just fill out every form they find.